# Common Literary Techniques for Drama Texts?

Tags: british-english, literature, poetry, literary-techniques

Right now we're studying a piece on drama (Disclosure: This is for school, but not necessarily for an essay or homework - It's just further study on other literary techniques that are used within drama texts.)

As drama texts are part of English Literature (Short stories, etc), they share some literary techniques with normal English Literature as well as English Poetry; However, it appears to me that there are numerous different techniques utilised for drama texts.

Could anyone list commonly used techniques for drama texts please?

So far, the words that I've compiled in my techniques list are:

- Sub-text
- Bathos
- Dramatic Irony
- Hyperbole
- Comic Relief
- Juxtaposition

Comment: Voting to close this question for being overly broad. This isn't a question that can be definitively answered.

Comment: joshdick: Agreed. Literature, and poetry in specific, are by definition free forms of expression. In the attempt to classify them and break them down you limit their expressive ability. Sure English teachers may try to fool you into thinking that a good story will involve elements X, Y, and Z- but that's because they are trying to standardize all children to make everyone mediocre rather than letting one person excel. If you really want a "general list" of these "techniques", try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literary_technique

Comment: In addition to the other objections, there is nothing special about "drama". You'll see the same literary devices in drama that you do in other literature. Even something like dramatic irony, despite having "drama" in its *name*, can appear in any literary medium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are a few tricks you may find used here and there. The most definitive list I've seen ( if not the most technical or academic ) is to be found at [TV Tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HomePage) - but be very careful- time vanishes on that site.